# Any way (without me writing JNI) for a Java app to operate by reference on Linux kernel /dev/shm data?

Tags: java, linux-kernel, java-native-interface, ipc

I know that Java can treat /dev/shm as a java.io.File and operate on /dev/shm contents by reading/copying same into the JVM (OS user address space).  Is there any solution that can empower a Java app to operate on /dev/shm contents by reference (i.e. no copying from kernel address space to user address space)?  I don't care if the solution is JNI based (assume it would have to be) -- but I don't want to have to write JNI.

Comment: You can also `mmap()` (albeit in a limited way) with Java. What do you call "/dev/shm contents" anyway?

Comment: You might get better performance from java.nio.

Comment: @fge -- in C++ you can use Linux system calls (shmop(2), shmat(2), shmctl(2), etc) to treat a secton of kernel address memory as a "shared memory attached" struct.  Fron the UFS view,this struct is hosted under /dev/shm/ and is observable re: perms/status/etc via Linux ipcs(1) util.  If I have a C++ process that writes to /dev/shm, I want to know if it is possible to have a Java app operate on that /dev/shm struct *by reference* (no copying).

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. SysV IPC, then. Java has no native support for that. If you don't want to use JNI, you can always use JNA. It is much easier to use.